# Greeting message for Lex bot

Tags: java, node.js, aws-lex

I am working on creating a lex bot and am fairly new to AWS Lex and Lambda. 
Is there a way to implement greetings in lex. 
Ex: 
Lex: Hi, how can I help you.
User: hello, I would like to make a purchase
.
.
I have tried Lambda initialization but it didn't work. Any code reference would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not believe this is possible in Lex itself. What interface are you going to provide your users? Web integration? Facebook? Slack? AWS Connect?

Comment: I'm planning to do a web integration.